# to generate textboxes dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to generate textboxes and dropdownboxes as html table columns dynamically.Like this I want to create 30 rows.how to do this in asp.net and c#.net?I want this in an asp.net page.

Comment: Can you be more specific, show some layout of what you need and some code you already got?

Answer (score 3):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtbx= null;    
        DropDownList ddl = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {               
            txtbx= new TextBox();
            txtbx.ID = "mytxt" + i; 
            txtbx.Text = "mytxt" + i;            

            pnlButton.Controls.Add(txtbx);    

            ddl= new DropDownList();
            ddl.ID = "mydropdown " + j;
            ddl.Text = "mydropdown " + j;
            ddl.Items.Add("Hii");
            ddl.Items.Add("Hello");
            ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
            ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_Click);

            pnlButton.Controls.Add(ddl);

            Literal lit = new Literal();
            lit.Text = "</br></br>";
            pnlButton.Controls.Add(lit);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. On the aspx page use a panel for showing controls in a proper way like this and a button for saving data in

   ```
   <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuestions" runat="server" Width="100%">
   </asp:Panel>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnNext" runat="server" CssClass="button" ToolTip="Next"
   OnClick="lbtnNext_Click"><span>Save & Next</span></asp:LinkButton>
   ```
2. On the code behind aspx.cs page, you can generate all dynamic controls on Page_Init event

   ```
   protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        TextBox txt = new  TextBox();
        txt.Text = QuestionText;
        txt.ID = "que1";
        pnlQuestions.Controls.Add(txt);
   }
   ```
3. You can get all dynamic controls value on button click event like this

   ```
    protected void lbtnNext_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
         TextBox txt = ((TextBox)pnlQuestions.FindControl("que1"));
         AnswerText = txt.Text.Trim();
         Response.Write(AnswerText); 
    }
   ```

By using this method you can generate and fetch dynamic controls on asp.net page.

for much more understanding : [Check this link](http://planetofcoders.blogspot.com/2011/05/run-time-dynamic-controls-in-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 1):

To start off you would need something like

```
<asp:Table ID="mytbl" runat="server">
    </asp:Table>
```

In the code behind then you can add as

```
TableRow trow;
TableCell tcell1, tcell2;
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
   trow = new TableRow();
   tcell1 = new TableCell();
   tcell1.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
   tcell2 = new TableCell();
   tcell2.Controls.Add(new DropDownList());
   trow.Cells.Add(tcell1);
   trow.Cells.Add(tcell2);
   mytbl.Rows.Add(trow);
}
```

Add as you require details for ID, Name and dropdown items as you need

Comment: if i want to assign a ajax calendar toolkit to one of the textboxes generated in the above way how to do it?

Comment: Create the control and set the target as the current textbox id you are generating, you can add multiple controls to a tablecell

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox box = new TextBox{ID="textbox1", Text="hello :)"};
    form1.Controls.Add(box);
}
```